# jquery addclass and remove class is not working in safari?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(elem).find('.ctl-qus-url-txt').on('click', function () {
  $(elem).find('input',".ctl-qus-url-txt").removeClass('ctl-inp-url-txt').select();
});
$(elem).find('.ctl-qus-url-txt').on('blur', function () {
    $(elem).find('input',".ctl-qus-url-txt").addClass('ctl-inp-url-txt');
});
```

Im trying to remove class on click and adding class on blur. It is working in all browsers, but not working in safari.

Comment: Safari on Mobile? This might help you https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html

Comment: Please post a jsfiddle, jsbin, or convert your example above into a StackOverflow snippet that demonstrates the problem so we can look further into it.